# Virtualhost on macos mamp ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost

I have a Mac under MacOS Big Sur (when I had Catalina, the problem was also present) with MAMP

I would like to create a virtual host

Here is what I did:

- in Application/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf, I uncommented the line
  `Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
- in /private/etc/hosts I added

```
127.0.0.1 test.deva
127.0.0.1 test.localhost
```

- here is my Application/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:8888>
 DocumentRoot /Aplications/MAMP/htdocs
 ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8888>
         DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testhost"
         ServerName test.deva
         ServerAlias www.test.deva
</VirtualHost>
```

In the parameters of MAMP I checked, I have the port 8888

In htdocs/testhost I just have an index.html file

i tried a lot of things i saw here on posts where the problem was the same
But I still have an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

How to do it please?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on macOS Big Sur with a Docker setup for local web development.
It turned out the problem was that **port 80**.

Changing the configuration to listen on **port 8080** solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks it's working but I can't access to test.deva but it's okay with test.deva:8080, how to change this ?